# SECURE LAN for File Transfer, 3 machines, upload/download from any machine to any machine

Tags: networking, server, ssh, lan

I would like to be able to access 3 different Ubuntu based machines securely, both upload and download, all on the same LAN. I need either written resources or step-by step instructions to setup all machines to act as host and client. What would be the best way to do this? Open-ssh?
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try SAMBA, easiest and secure to do transfer from one machine to other.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync will help you for a long time going forward. Its powerful and comes with so many useful features like resume support, synchronize only new files, LAN or remote host support, etc.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-rsync-to-sync-local-and-remote-directories-on-a-vps